# Is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is $\Omega$ a Banach (sub)space?

Comment: Typically, "Banach space" refers to a set endowed a $\Bbb R$-or-$\Bbb C$ vector space structure (plus stuff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subspaces of $\mathbf R^n$ are all unbounded and closed.

Comment: Non trivial subspaces :)

Comment: Touche.$\mbox{}$

Answer (score 4):

A Banach subspace is a linear subspace.  Part of the definition of that is being closed under multiplication by scalars, i.e. if $x \in S$ then $tx \in S$ for all scalars $t$.  Since $\|tx\| = |t| \|x\|$, the only bounded set that satisfies this is $\{0\}$.  But $\{0\}$ is not open.